# Getting org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): No lease on in par

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

Trying to process each JSON file from a HDFS directory and write into a HDFS directory. Here I am using Scala parallel collection par. I am trying below code to read JSON file.

**Code:**

```
val lines2 =Source.fromFile("allats_tmp.txt").getLines.toList.filter(x => x.size > 1) 
val ooo = lines2.par.foreach(x => {
         var path = path of hdfs directory 
         val readJSON = sc.wholeTextFiles(path) 
         val dataFrame = spark.read.json(readJSON.toSeq.toDS) 
         dataFrame.coalesce(1).write.mode("append").json("appendedjsontestpar") 
})
```

I am getting below error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): 
No lease on /user/ine12363287/appendedjsontestpar/_SUCCESS (inode 2013174239):
File does not exist. 
[Lease.  Holder: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1536968823_1, pendingcreates: 2]
```

Comment: val lines2 =Source.fromFile("allats_tmp.txt").getLines.toList.filter(x => x.size > 1)
val ooo = lines2.par.foreach(x => {var path = path of hdfs directory
val readJSON = sc.wholeTextFiles(path)
val dataFrame = spark.read.json(readJSON.toSeq.toDS)
dataFrame.coalesce(1).write.mode("append").json("appendedjsontestpar")
})

Answer (score 0):

You can simply read multiple `json` files using `json()` function available in Spark.

Case 1: If you are having all `json` files in same `HDFS` directory, then just pass the `json` files `HDFS` path to json function as below.

Syntax: `spark.read.json("<hdfs_path>")`

Case 2: If you are having your `json` files in different `HDFS` directories, then you can use same Function `json(paths:String*)` which accepts variable arguments as well.

Syntax: `spark.read.json("<hdfs_path1>","<hdfs_path2>")`